# How does angularjs react for changes of objects in the scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

If there is a view that displays elements in an array, and the array grows; how does angular refresh the DOM? Does it just append the new elements to the existing view or recreates the whole thing?

I fear that I might run into a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) if I keep adding stuff to lists...

Comment: angular js use dirty checking :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api appends a new element to the end of the dom tree (well at least the section you are working with) or beginning depending on the filter mechanic you implement. You should be safe, adding as many elements you like of course there is a limit to how big you can get in reality. However for sane amounts of items you should be perfectly fine.